# How to fix wix creating multiple instance on every MSI build of same product version?

Tags: wix

Please help me in How to fix wix creating multiple instance on every MSI build of same product version?
- on every MSI build using Wix is creating a new entry in control panel. I am not pushing any new versions.

Please help. This is how my wxs file look like

```
<Product Id="*" Name="*************" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0" Manufacturer="********" UpgradeCode="31C4854C-14E4-4851-901A-921E0B1A54C1">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="*********" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="F_FullApplication" Title="Full Application" Level="1" Description="All Services" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="C_CommonAssemblies" />
    </Feature>

    <Binary Id="************"
            src="..\*********\bin\$(var.Configuration)\*********.dll" />

  </Product>
```

Comment: Since you already have a MajorUpgrade element, you don't need any of "<Upgrade Id="31C4854C-14E4-4851-901A-921E0B1A54C1">
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="2.0.0.0" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" /> 
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.8.0.1" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="2.0.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" /> "

Answer (score 1):

First, there are 3 types of upgrade: major upgrade, minor update and small update. Since you define the element "MajorUpgrade", you're making a major upgrade a each new release. In that case you must also remove

```
<Upgrade Id="31C4854C-14E4-4851-901A-921E0B1A54C1">
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="2.0.0.0" OnlyDetect="yes"      Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" /> 
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.8.0.1" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="2.0.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" />
```

and generate a new product guid at each build (for example by setting the "Id" attribute of your "Product" element to "*"). Please carefully read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx.
I suggest you to document yourself for the type of upgrade that suits your needs.

Second if you want the same version to upgrade itself, your MajorUpgrade element must define the attribute "AllowSameVersionUpgrades" to "yes". Cf http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html
Please note that 2 instances of your installers which differ only in the fourth version number are considered having the same version (example: 2.3.21.111 is the same version than 2.3.21.423, but not 2.3.22.231)

**Edit**: This works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="vinod" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="brainless" UpgradeCode="cfd6535c-0037-4463-a71a-f206448638ce">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="vinod" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="MyComp" />
    </Feature>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="vinod">
                <Component Guid="82fb8081-05d4-4b71-8f74-97983797741d" Id="MyComp">
                    <File Id="MyFile" Name="myfile.dll" Source="$(env.DllDir)myfile.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Product>
```

Comment: I tried the options suggested - no luck.Can you please help?

Comment: You're edited sample code works for me. Please try to add the attribute AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" in the MajorUpgrade element.

Comment: When I tried  IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes" on MajorUpgrade it worked. But it ignores the error. I am not sure is it good to do that.

Comment: What error? You can also generate a log: run your installer from command line: msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi /l*v log.txt. And also be sure to remove all already installed instances from control panel, then generate version 1.0.0.0, then generate version 1.0.0.1 (or any version bigger than the previous one), installe the first version then the second. From Control Panel there should be only the latest version installed.